# What combination of services in AWS should I use for a system with high availability?

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, web-architecture

We are building a serverless system. Right now what we are using is Cognito for user authentication, S3 for static storage, API gateway, Lambda function and Aurora Serverless for this system. This system is quite simple, it includes user registration, no search, no join query. I wonder what else I can do to improve the availability.

Comment: Test it under load and see where it fails.

Comment: In what sense you would like to improve "availability"? Serverless architectures are by their nature highly available as they are not bound into one instance or a single availability zone.